# Import error from pytorch lightning import seed_everything on stable warpfusion v0.14.13

Tags: python-3.x, google-colaboratory, pytorch-lightning

i've searched on [pytorch's official website](https://lightning.ai/docs/pytorch/latest/) but still had no idea about what happen, i was try it in google collabs and local installation but still same issues, it seems like 'seed_everything' function doesn't exist at pytorch_lightning modules, but how i know where's the 'seed_everything' function??

notes :

- **i was use 0.14.13 version**

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[11], line 94
     92 from contextlib import nullcontext
     93 import time
---> 94 from pytorch_lightning import seed_everything
     96 os.chdir(f"{root_dir}/stablediffusion")
     97 from ldm.util import instantiate_from_config

File ~\code\WarpFusion\v0.14.13\env\lib\site-packages\pytorch_lightning\__init__.py:34
     31     _logger.addHandler(logging.StreamHandler())
     32     _logger.propagate = False
---> 34 from pytorch_lightning.callbacks import Callback  # noqa: E402
     35 from pytorch_lightning.core import LightningDataModule, LightningModule  # noqa: E402
     36 from pytorch_lightning.trainer import Trainer  # noqa: E402

File ~\code\WarpFusion\v0.14.13\env\lib\site-packages\pytorch_lightning\callbacks\__init__.py:25
     23 from pytorch_lightning.callbacks.model_summary import ModelSummary
     24 from pytorch_lightning.callbacks.prediction_writer import BasePredictionWriter
---> 25 from pytorch_lightning.callbacks.progress import ProgressBarBase, RichProgressBar, TQDMProgressBar
     26 from pytorch_lightning.callbacks.pruning import ModelPruning
     27 from pytorch_lightning.callbacks.quantization import QuantizationAwareTraining

File ~\code\WarpFusion\v0.14.13\env\lib\site-packages\pytorch_lightning\callbacks\progress\__init__.py:22
     14 """
     15 Progress Bars
     16 =============
   (...)
     19 
     20 """
     21 from pytorch_lightning.callbacks.progress.base import ProgressBarBase  # noqa: F401
---> 22 from pytorch_lightning.callbacks.progress.rich_progress import RichProgressBar  # noqa: F401
     23 from pytorch_lightning.callbacks.progress.tqdm_progress import TQDMProgressBar

File ~\code\WarpFusion\v0.14.13\env\lib\site-packages\pytorch_lightning\callbacks\progress\rich_progress.py:20
     17 from datetime import timedelta
     18 from typing import Any, Dict, Optional, Union
---> 20 from torchmetrics.utilities.imports import _compare_version
     22 import pytorch_lightning as pl
     23 from pytorch_lightning.callbacks.progress.base import ProgressBarBase

ImportError: cannot import name '_compare_version' from 'torchmetrics.utilities.imports' (C:\Users\xoNezx\code\WarpFusion\v0.14.13\env\lib\site-packages\torchmetrics\utilities\imports.py)
```

i'm just try to run stable warpfusion normally following the creator's tutorial from [the owner's github](https://github.com/Sxela/WarpFusion) and then this happen. i was looking for [the tutorial for the same version](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tUHCtQaBWCw) but it's different

Comment: I remember it solved with different version installation. Could you downgrade `pip install torchmetrics==0.11.4`?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Only some versions of pytpytorch-lightning have seed_everything.

Try `pip install pytorch-lightning==1.8.4`

then type:

```
from pytorch_lightning.utilities.seed import seed_everything
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you installed the compatible version of pytorch_lightning. In my case I did

```
pip install pytorch_lightning==1.7.7
```

Alternative work around
go to C:\Users\xoNezx\code\WarpFusion\v0.14.13\env\lib\site-packages\torchmetrics\utilities\imports.py

Replace _compare_version with compare_version

The issue I faced was in
\pytorch_lightning\callbacks\progress\rich_progress.py

All what I did to over come this issue is
change

```
from torchmetrics.utilities.imports import _compare_version
```

to

```
from torchmetrics.utilities.imports import compare_version
```

And change

```
_RICH_AVAILABLE: bool = _package_available("rich") and _compare_version("rich", operator.ge, "10.2.2")
```

to

```
_RICH_AVAILABLE: bool = _package_available("rich") and compare_version("rich", operator.ge, "10.2.2")
```

Answer (score -1):

The source code of the instance `seed_everything` uses the `lightning_fabric` library. So make sure you have installed this library in your notebook.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35074898)